# How to save data in a composable function with view model constructor

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a composable function for the home screen, whenever I navigate to a new composable and come back to this function everything is re created. Do I have to move the view model somewhere higher?
home screen

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: NFTViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val feedState by viewModel.nftResponse.observeAsState()

   
    if (feedState?.status == Result.Status.SUCCESS) {
        val nfts = feedState?.data?.content
        LazyColumn {
            itemsIndexed(nfts!!) { index, item ->
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(15.dp)
                        .clickable { },
                    elevation = 8.dp
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)
                    ) {
                        Image(
                            painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                                item.firebaseUri
                            ),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
                            modifier = Modifier.height(250.dp)
                        )
                        Text(
                            buildAnnotatedString {
                                append("Contract Address: ")
                                withStyle(
                                    style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.W900, color = Color(0xFF4552B8))
                                ) {
                                    append(item.contractAddress)
                                }
                            }
                        )
                        Text(
                            buildAnnotatedString {
                                append("Chain: ")
                                withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.W900)) {
                                    append(item.chain.displayName)
                                }
                                append("")
                            }
                        )
                        Text(
                            buildAnnotatedString {
                                append("Price: ")
                                withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.W900)) {
                                    append(item.price)
                                }
                                append("")
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(colorResource(id = R.color.white))
                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Feed",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                color = Color.DarkGray,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontSize = 25.sp
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Navigation

```
@Composable
fun Navigation(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = NavigationItem.Home.route) {
       composable(NavigationItem.Home.route) {
            val vm: NFTViewModel = viewModel()
            HomeScreen(vm)
        }
        composable(NavigationItem.Add.route) {
            AddScreen()
        }
        composable(NavigationItem.Wallets.route) {
            WalletsScreen()
        }
        composable(NavigationItem.Popular.route) {
            PopularScreen()
        }
        composable(NavigationItem.Profile.route) {
            ProfileScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like I need to save the view model as a state or something? I seem to be missing something. Basically I dont want to trigger getFeed() everytime the composable function is called, where do I save the data in the compose function, in the view model?

EDIT now calling getFeed from init in the view model

```
class NFTViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val nftRepository = NFTRepository()
    private var successResult: Result<NftResponse>? = null

    private var _nftResponse = MutableLiveData<Result<NftResponse>>()
    val nftResponse: LiveData<Result<NftResponse>>
        get() = _nftResponse

    init {
        successResult?.let {
            _nftResponse.postValue(successResult!!)
        } ?: kotlin.run {
            getFeed() //this is always called still successResult is always null
        }

    }

    private fun getFeed() {

        viewModelScope.launch {

            _nftResponse.postValue(Result(Result.Status.LOADING, null, null))

            val data = nftRepository.getFeed()

            if (data.status == Result.Status.SUCCESS) {
                successResult = data
                _nftResponse.postValue(Result(Result.Status.SUCCESS, data.data, data.message))
            } else {
                _nftResponse.postValue(Result(Result.Status.ERROR, null, data.message))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        Timber.tag(Constants.TIMBER).d("onCleared")
        super.onCleared()
    }
}
```

However it still seems like a new view model is being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like I need to save the view model as a state or something?

You don't have to. `ViewModel`s are already preserved as part of their owner scope. The same `ViewModel` instance will be returned to you if you retrieve the `ViewModel`s correctly.

> I seem to be missing something.

You are initializing a new instance of your `NFTViewModel` every time the navigation composable recomposes (gets called) instead of retrieving the `NFTViewModel` from its `ViewModelStoreOwner`.

You should retrieve `ViewModel`s by calling `viewModel()` or if you are using Hilt and `@HiltViewModel` then call `hiltViewModel()` instead.

No Hilt

```kotlin
val vm: NFTViewModel = viewModel()
```

> Returns an existing `ViewModel` or creates a new one in the given owner (usually, a fragment or an activity), defaulting to the owner provided by `LocalViewModelStoreOwner`.
> The created `ViewModel` is associated with the given `viewModelStoreOwner` and will be retained as long as the owner is alive (e.g. if it is an activity, until it is finished or process is killed).

If using Hilt (i.e. your `ViewModel` has the `@HiltViewModel` annotation)

```kotlin
val vm: NFTViewModel = hiltViewModel()
```

> Returns an existing `@HiltViewModel`-annotated `ViewModel` or creates a new one scoped to the current navigation graph present on the `NavController` back stack.
> If no navigation graph is currently present then the current scope will be used, usually, a fragment or an activity.

The above will preserve your view model state, however you are still resetting the state inside your composable if your composable exits the composition and then re-enters it at a later time, which happens every time you navigate to a different screen (to a different "screen" composable, if it is just a dialog then the previous composable won't leave the composition, because it will be still displayed in the background).

Due to this part of the code

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: NFTViewModel) {
    val feedState by viewModel.nftResponse.observeAsState()

    // this resets to false when HomeScreen leaves and later
    // re-enters the composition
    val fetched = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    if (!fetched.value) {
        fetched.value = true
        viewModel.getFeed()
    }
```

`fetched` will always be false when you navigate to (and back to) `HomeScreen` and thus `getFeed()` will be called.
If you don't want to call `getFeed()` when you navigate back to `HomeScreen` you have to store the `fetched` value somewhere else, probably inside your `NFTViewModel` and only reset it to `false` when you want that `getFeed()` is called again.

Comment: I made some changes but its still created a new instance of the view model, or at least init is firing every time. I made some changes can you check them out @Ma3x

Comment: Ok now it works when I use 
```
composable(NavigationItem.Home.route) {
            val vm: NFTViewModel = viewModel()
            HomeScreen(vm)
        }
```

Comment: @Brian Yes, that is correct. After you retrieve your `ViewModel` you then pass it to your `HomeScreen`. After you edited the constructor with the default value like `fun HomeScreen(viewModel: NFTViewModel = viewModel())`, even just calling `HomeScreen()` without a parameter would work now.